# Why does the orientation of my web page change to landscape and the zooming go changing funny when focused inside a textarea?

Tags: css

When I load the web page in portrait on my smartphone, it shows all three columns underneath each other. When I load it in landscape, it shows all columns side by side. This is expected behaviour.

What is not expected behaviour, is that when I focus inside a text box, the layout messes up as the viewport changes. The culprit is the CSS below.

```
/* Landscape */
@media screen  and (orientation:landscape) {
    #acceptside, #neutralside, #rejectside { width: 33.3% !important; }
    /* Landscape styles */
}
```

But it's only supposed to make the columns 33% when it's landscape. So why is that line of code being triggered when the textarea is focused on in portrait?

I have a test example here. https://compesh.com/test.html

Answer (score -1):

It is because of large font-size in the textarea. Try reducing the font-size (which is set to 2em currently).

Edit: 
In File:
    https://compesh.com/assets/teststylesheet.css
Rule:

```
 textarea:focus {
    min-height: 4.35em !important;
}
```

is causing this. Removing this rule solves the problem.

Comment: I have changed the font size in the textarea to 1px and it didn't do anything.

Comment: Hmm...I did it in https://compesh.com/test.html and it worked. Maybe it has to do something with the rows attribute. I'm working on it.

Comment: I **need** to have that CSS rule in my stylesheet, so that when people edit comments on my website from a mobile phone, the textarea isn't too small, so I cannot remove that CSS rule. Why would changing the min-height or height of an element change the orientation to landscape? I need the web browser to respect the orientation rule in my CSS, but it is not.